# How I access redis in twisted factory method?

Tags: redis, twisted

I am using redis to keep tracking all connected clients/devices. The socket server is written with Twisted. Since the status of redis has to be initialized before running socket server, and synchrounized after geting TERM signal from OS. I would like to implement two factory methods.

I tried to implement the code as following. but failed.

```py
import txredisapi as redis
from twisted.internet import defer

conf = EpicConf().loadConf()
dbid = string.atoi(conf['Redisdbid'])
rcs =  redis.lazyConnection(password=conf['RedisPassword'], dbid=dbid, reconnect=True)
dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb",db=conf['DbName'],user=conf['DbAccount'],\
        passwd=conf['DbPassword'],host=conf['DbHost'],\
        use_unicode=True,charset=conf['DbCharset'],cp_reconnect=True)

class PlainTCP(protocol.Protocol, TimeoutMixin):
    global conf

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

class PlainTCPFactory(protocol.Factory):
    global conf
    onlineDevices = 'GlinkOnlineDevices'
    timezone = 8 # for CST +8

    def __init__(self):
        global conf
        print "Info: Version={}, TimeOutIdle={}".format(__version__, conf['TimeOutIdle'])

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return PlainTCP(self)

    #@defer.inlineCallbacks
    def startFactory(self):
        #global rcs
        print "beforeRunning(): clean redis for running"
        #yield rcs.delete(self.onlineDevices)

    #@defer.inlineCallbacks
    def stopFactory(self):
        #global rcs
        print "afterRunning(): load from redis for logging"
        #yield rcs.delete(self.onlineDevices)

def main():
    #or another init redis operations here
    reactor.listenTCP(6000, PlainTCPFactory(), interface="0.0.0.0")
    reactor.run
    #or another sync redis operations here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From the code snippet, you can see I have tried to add code in two factory methods:

- startFactory()
- stopFactory()

But @defer.inlinecallbacks and yield will throw errors as following if I uncomment startFactory():

```py
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1107, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "EpicGlinkTcpServer.py", line 887, in startFactory
            yield rcs.delete(self.onlineDevices)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txredisapi-1.2-py2.7.egg/txredisapi.py", line 1698, in wrapper
            d = self._factory.getConnection()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1253, in unwindGenerator
            return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1107, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txredisapi-1.2-py2.7.egg/txredisapi.py", line 2037, in getConnection
            raise ConnectionError("Not connected")
        txredisapi.ConnectionError: Not connected
```

And throw following errors if I uncomment stopFactory().

```py
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [BaseRedisProtocol,client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x9951e2c> will retry in 2 seconds
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [BaseRedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0x9951dac>
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [__main__.PlainTCPFactory] (TCP Port 6000 Closed)
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [__main__.PlainTCPFactory] Stopping factory <__main__.PlainTCPFactory instance at 0x9962aac>
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [__main__.PlainTCPFactory] afterRunning(): load from redis for logging
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [__main__.PlainTCPFactory] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-09-02 16:11:24+0800 [__main__.PlainTCPFactory] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1107, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "EpicGlinkTcpServer.py", line 893, in stopFactory
            yield rcs.delete(self.onlineDevices)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txredisapi-1.2-py2.7.egg/txredisapi.py", line 1698, in wrapper
            d = self._factory.getConnection()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1253, in unwindGenerator
            return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1107, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txredisapi-1.2-py2.7.egg/txredisapi.py", line 2037, in getConnection
            raise ConnectionError("Not connected")
        txredisapi.ConnectionError: Not connected
```

I have no clue on how to implement correct code here. I have two more options.

1. Add another synchrouns redis library, regardless current txredisapi, add two code in main().
2. Add scripts in external bash shell script.

However, if someone can help me to implement in factory methods. that will be perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check below example I think it can help you.

**redis.py**

```py
import txredis
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

REDIS = None
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 6379

# Making connection ##############################################
def create_connection():
    client_creator = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, txredis.RedisClient)
    df = client_creator.connectTCP(HOST, PORT)
    df.addCallback(connection_success)
    df.addErrback(cannot_connect)

# connection created
def connection_success(redis_protocol):
    global REDIS
    REDIS = redis_protocol

def cannot_connect(error):
    print(error)


def getRedis():
    global REDIS
    return REDIS

create_connection()`
```

**main.py**

```py
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

from redis import getRedis


class MyProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print(self)


class MyFactory(ServerFactory):

    protocol = MyProtocol
    onlineDevices = 'GlinkOnlineDevices'

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print(getRedis())
        p = self.protocol()
        p.factory = self
        return p

    def startFactory(self):
        def success(result):
            print(result)

        def gotError(error):
            print(error)

        redis = getRedis()
        df = redis.delete(self.onlineDevices)
        df.addCallback(success)
        df.addErrback(gotError)

    def stopFactory(self):
        redis = getRedis()

def startService():
    reactor.listenTCP(6000, MyFactory())

reactor.callLater(2, startService)
reactor.run()
```

Here I started factory after 2 seconds, to establish redis connection before the factory initialized.

And for convenience I suggest don't access Redis object in the factory, instead, you can add the required method in Redis class which performing the operation in the Redis database.

I hope this can help you.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Lalit. Before receiving your comments, I added extra code in start/shutdown shell script with redis-cli and lua code to do some clean jobs. However your implementation is preferred.